# OIDC Flow in ASP.NET Core 7.0 Web API against Google

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, authentication, asp.net-web-api, openid-connect

I want to authenticate users in my Web API using the OIDC flow and Google as the ID provider.

In a nutshell, my application is composed of multiple microservices where each is a Web API. The authNZ to the REST endpoints in all the services is through JWT. I have one identity microservice that I want it to implement the OIDC flow, particularly implementing the following three REST endpoints.

- `login` that returns a `Challenge` (or its URL);
- `logout` endpoint.
- `callback` that is called by Google and should extract user information from the OIDC code (including ID and Access tokens);

[Most Microsoft templates](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/identity-api-authorization?view=aspnetcore-7.0) for AuthNZ are either mostly built with UI elements or leverage third-party libraries such as Duende, which I cannot use.

I can redirect to Google using the `Singin` endpoint, though `code` is `null` when Google call's back the redirect URI. So, I am not sure what is missing in my configuration.

```cs
// Register services
services.AddAuthentication(options =>
{
    options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = GoogleDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    options.DefaultChallengeScheme = GoogleDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
})
.AddGoogle(options =>
{
    options.ClientId = "...";
    options.ClientSecret = "...";
});

// Configure App
app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();
```

The controller.

```cs
[Route("api/v1/[controller]/[action]")]
[ApiController]
[Authorize]
public class IdentityController : ControllerBase
{
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [HttpGet]
    public IActionResult SignIn()
    {
        return new ChallengeResult(
            "Google",
            new AuthenticationProperties
            {
                IsPersistent = true,
                RedirectUri = Url.Action("callback", "Identity") 
            });
    }

    [AllowAnonymous]
    [HttpGet(Name = "callback")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Callback(object code = null)
    {
        // code is null here.
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Callback endpoint should be implemented like the following.

```cs
[AllowAnonymous]
[HttpGet(Name = "callback")]
public async Task<IActionResult> callback()
{
    var authResult = await HttpContext.AuthenticateAsync(
        GoogleDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
    var claims = authResult.Principal.Identities
        .FirstOrDefault().Claims.Select(claim => new
        {
            claim.Issuer,
            claim.OriginalIssuer,
            claim.Type,
            claim.Value
        });
    return Content(claims.ToString());
}
```

I have been using cookies to get the authentication results, as suggested by some blogs, as the following, though that did not work for me.

```cs
// An incorrect method of getting 
// authentication results in my use-case.
var authResult = await HttpContext.AuthenticateAsync(
    CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
```

Answer (score 0):

You typically don't use AddGoogle on its own,instead you add **AddCookie()** as well. So that the application can create a user session cookie.

```
.AddGoogle(options =>
{
    options.ClientId = "...";
    options.ClientSecret = "...";
});
```

See this blog post for more details
https://www.roundthecode.com/dotnet/how-to-add-google-authentication-to-a-asp-net-core-application

Also, make sure you set Cookies as the default authentication scheme

```
options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = GoogleDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
```

Comment: I followed the steps in the blogpost with no joy. In the callback, the `result.Principal` is `null`.  My other concern with the steps discussed in that post is that it reads "we are not using `Identity`", while I am interested in using `Identity`.

Comment: AddGoogle's role is to authenticate the user, and usually it will create an AuthentictionTicket and send it to the AddCookie handler, that then will issue a session cookie and create the ClaimsPrincipal user.

Comment: You usually use both together. does this work? http://www.voidgeeks.com/tutorial/How-to-Add-Google-Authentication-in-ASPNET-Core-Application/17

Comment: Appreciate your suggestion, though I still have the same issue: `result.Principal` is `null`.